# Adding the public circle to Google+'s PlusShare.Builder

Tags: android, google-plus

I'm using PlusShare.Builder to create a share intent in my android application. There is a setRecipients method in it that lets me add a list of Persons to the intent. Instead of adding a list of persons, I just want it so that the Public Circle is selected as a recipient for the share message. I can't seem to find how that is done. Has anyone done this before?

Comment: I know about limitation in 10 Persons but if I add only one person object in the list like 'PlusShare.createPerson("106189723444098348646","Larry Page")' than after startActivityForResult I don't see that this person is in recipient field. What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The [Interactive Post](https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/interactive) feature allows prefilling up to 10 recipients by user ID or by email address.  It does not allow prefilling of Circles, or of the Extended Circles or Public share options.  It only allows IDs and email addresses, therefore only allowing up to 10 specific people to be shared with.

From the specification for `data-recipients`:

"A comma-separated list of user IDs and email addresses that you want to prefill the share settings with. You can get these IDs by calling the people.list method on behalf of an authenticated user. A maximum of ten recipients are allowed."